# Get the same result with ResizeObserver and media query

Tags: javascript, css, dom, window-resize

I have globally defined `breakpoints`:

```js
breakpoints: {
  xs: "0px",
  sm: "320px",
  md: "672px",
  lg: "1056px",
  xl: "1312px",
},
```

I also have `media queries` to define the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`, based on previous `breakpoints`:

```css
@media (min-width: 672px) {
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
@media (min-width: 0px) {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

And finally, I am using `ResizeObserver` to observer `document.body` and set the `paddingLeft`, for example:

```js
const observer = new ResizeObserver(([entry]) => {
  if (entry.contentRect.width >= Number.parseInt(breakpoints.xl)) {
    document.body.style.paddingLeft = "10em"
  } else if (entry.contentRect.width >= Number.parseInt(breakpoints.lg)) {
    document.body.style.paddingLeft = "10em"
  } else if (entry.contentRect.width >= Number.parseInt(breakpoints.md)) {
    document.body.style.paddingLeft = "10em"
  } else if (entry.contentRect.width >= Number.parseInt(breakpoints.xs)) {
    document.body.style.paddingLeft = "5em"
  }
})

observer.observe(document.body)
```

The trouble is that the `padding-top` or `padding-bottom` (media queries) don't change at same time that the `paddingLeft` (ResizeObserver) and I don't know why and how to solve.

--- EDITED ---

I hope it is better understood now:

Please see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8jryn509/) and resize the result to see how the `div` change the `padding-top` and the `paddingLeft` at a different time.

Comment: Firstly, `if` conditions not closed with `)`. Then, you are only changing `paddingTop` and expecting `paddingBottom` to change. How?

Comment: Fixed the `if` conditions and changed `paddingTop` by `paddingLeft`, I hope it is better understood now @User863

Comment: check correct media query syntax [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). That is you missed the body selector.

Comment: Please see: https://jsfiddle.net/8jryn509/ and resize the result to see how the `div` change the `padding-top` and the `paddingLeft` at a different time. @User863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contentRect` is the element's content box, without paddings, border, and margins. Due to the `body` elements's default `margin: 8px;` and scrollbar width, the `entry.contentRect.width` will be 33px less than the window width.

```
16px (body margin) + 17px (scollbar width) = 33px
```

**References**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserverEntry/contentRect

https://xebia.com/blog/resize-observer-api-detecting-element-size-change/

**Alternatively**, you can use [`MediaQueryList.onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/onchange)

> A MediaQueryList object stores information on a media query applied to
> a document, with support for both immediate and event-driven matching
> against the state of the document.

**Example** with one breakpoint

```
const element = document.getElementById("test");

var mql = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 672px)');

mql.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  if (e.matches) {
    element.style.paddingLeft = "10em"
  } else {
    element.style.paddingLeft = "unset"
  }
})
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/9rmg5bzh/)**

Comment: In my project a have setted `body { margin: 0px }` so I imagine the trouble is the scroll, but using `entry.target.offsetWidth` don't solve the issue and if I understand correctly `offsetWidth` include the scroll (see https://jsfiddle.net/7L5bg29x/) Thanks @User863